# Is it possible to make Resharper dash case new files?

Tags: javascript, typescript, resharper

When I made a class in my Typescript/Javascript it looks like this:

```
export class ContainerContract {
```

but when I make the file I dash case it like this:

```
container-contract.ts
```

But Resharper wants to make a file that matches the class name: `ContainerContract.ts` (like I would do in C#).

[image: Resharper Doesn't Dash Case]

**Is there a way to get Resharper to do dash casing in new files for typescript and javascript?**